# From string to list in prolog

Tags: prolog

In Prolog i have created a simple program that takes as input an atomic string, read it via the read operator and then trasform it into a list with the ASCII codes of the string's characted.
However, i used the built-in operator **string_to_list**.

```
string_list(L):-
    read(A),
    string_to_list(A,L).
```

This version of the program doensn't satisfy me. In fact i prefer not to use built in predicate.

What can i do to produce the same output without using the buil in predicate **string_to_list** ?

Comment: At some point, you'll need to use a library call to break an atom down to a list of character codes. `atom_codes/2` for example.

Comment: or `atom_chars/2`, and figure out the conversion from a single-char atom to ASCII code by yourself.